# SQL Unique Values from each column

Tags: mysql, sql

So I am trying to get unique values from each column. So far I have tried.

Day: Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday

Time: 8-10am, 10-12pm, 1-3pm, 3-5pm, 5-7pm

```
SELECT DISTINCT Day, Time FROM table GROUP BY Day, Time;
```

EXAMPLE:

```
Monday    8-10am
Monday    3-5pm
Monday    5-7pm
Tuesday   10-12pm
Tuesday   5-7pm
Wednesday 3-5pm
Thursday  10-12pm
Thursday   1-3pm
Friday    8-10am
Friday    1-3pm
```

This would not give me a unique value for each column, but unique value for each TIME in a DAY.

```
SELECT
(SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT Day) FROM workingTimeDate) as Day,
(SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT Time) FROM workingTimeDate) as Time
FROM workingTimeDate;
```

This would give:

```
Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday   8-10am,10-12pm,1-3pm,3-5pm,5-7pm
```

This would group up the values into two column, but I want them in separate columns.

What I want is

```
Day        Time
Monday     8-10am
Tuesday    10-12pm
Wednesday  1-3pm
Thursday   3-5pm
Friday     5-7pm
```

Comment: Better to show us sample data and expected output

Comment: Show some sample data so we can actually understand your problem regarding unique values.

Comment: Why would someone want to do that? There is no relation between `Day` and `Time` in your result set. It's also possible that the number of distinct days and the number of distinct times is not equal.

Comment: I agree with Paul Spiegel. Make this two separate queries, one for distinct days, another for distinct times.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
select distinct day, cast(NULL as time) from t
union all
select distinct cast(NULL as date), time from t;
```

Comment: I guess but is it possible to remove the null?

Answer (score 0):

So what you want is:

```
 select Day, 
        group_concat(time, ', ') as t
   FROM table 
  GROUP BY Day
```

Comment: This at least would make sence.